# How to get notifications of changes in contacts even when the application is closed

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, contentobserver

My app "syncs" all the contacts on a phone with the server. However, part of the requirement is that if any contact is inserted, updated, or deleted then the sync must happen again to maintain data integrity. I know about registering a `ContentObserver` on `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, but any such observer would have to be unregistered on the Activity's `onPause()`, and thus would not get notifications if the app wasn't running at that moment.

I also do not want to implement a content observer in a service, since [services aren't permanent either.](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/)  Plus, I don't like the idea of running something in the background 24x7.

So, is there any way by which I can detect that the contacts have changed since a sync? I do not need a real-time notification, so it's ok if this detection only happens when the app is run next.

Comment: Found any solution to this yet?

Comment: Nope, nothing. I ended up periodically computing a hash of all current contacts (when the phone is connected to a charger), and comparing it to the previous stored hash. If the two hashes mismatch, then I perform the sync again.

Comment: I encountered in the same issue and did a similar solution. Did you found any solution??